# refstepcounter inside description item

Tags: labels, counters, description

My purpose is to create visual steps in proofs.

I cooked this from the environment `description`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{subproofcount}
\newcommand{\thesubproffcount}{\arabic{subproofcount}}
\newcommand{\subprooflabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{subproofcount}(\roman{subproofcount}) \underline{\bf #1}}

\newenvironment{subproof}{\let\Olddescriptionlabel\descriptionlabel\let\descriptionlabel\subprooflabel \begin{description}\setcounter{subproofcount}{0}}{\end{description}\let\descriptionlabel\Olddescriptionlabel}



\begin{document}
    Here is a proof.
    \section{Title 1}
    \section{Title 2}
    \begin{subproof}
        \item[\( A\) is open]       \label{ITEMone}
            Let \( \epsilon>0\) etc.
        \item[\( A\) is bounded] 
            Suppose etc. Using \ref{ITEMone}
    \end{subproof}
\end{document}
```

The items are correctly numbered:

[image: output]

My problem is that `\ref{ITEMone}` creates a reference to the section (i.e. "2" in this example) instead of a reference to the `subproof` item (i.e. (i) in the example).

EDIT: Best answer for my use case here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697316/109167

Comment: Why are you using a `description` environment instead of an `enumerate` environment?

Comment: The most logical explanation is that `\refstepcounter` is inside a group and `\@currentlable` is local to that group.  It would probably be easier to create a new list environment from scratch.

Comment: @Mico Honestly I don't remember. I did it several years ago; I remember to have tried both `description` and `enumerate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses a new list environment.  Note that the default `\item` does not increment the counter when an optional argument is used.

The only remaining question is whether to place the left margin to the left or right of the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\newcounter{subproofcount}
\renewcommand{\thesubproofcount}{\roman{subproofcount}}
\newcommand{\subprooflabel}[1]{\hbox to \leftmargin{\hfill(\thesubproofcount)\hspace\labelsep}\underline{\bf #1}}
\newcommand{\subproofitem}[1][]{\refstepcounter{subproofcount}\csname @item\endcsname[#1]}

\newenvironment{subproof}{\let\item=\subproofitem
  \list{subproofcount}{\usecounter{subproofcount}\let\makelabel=\subprooflabel}}%
  {\endlist}

\begin{document}
    Here is a proof.
    \section{Title 1}
    \section{Title 2}
    \begin{subproof}
        \item[\( A\) is open]       \label{ITEMone}
            Let \( \epsilon>0\) etc.\\
            Add another line.
        \item[\( A\) is bounded] 
            Suppose etc. Using \ref{ITEMone}
    \end{subproof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I do two subproofs in the same document, I get warnings: "destination with the same identifier (name{subproofcount.2}) has been already used". So if I refer to the point (iii), in fact it refer to point (iii) of the *first* subproof. hyperref makes a wrong link, but this is not big deal.

Comment: Hyperref redefines `\item` to activate the target name `Item.\theitem`.  However, I have to bypass `\item` and go directly to `\@item`.  So when using hyperref you need need to add `\@hyper@itemtrue` to `\subproofitem`.   (use `\makeatletter`)

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since the numbers -- (i), (ii), etc -- in the step-by-step proof are at least as visible as the associated descriptive labels, I would create a bespoke enumerated environment called `subproof` with the help of the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros. That way, cross-referencing items via `\label` and `\ref` is completely straightforward.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}  % for \uline macro
\newcommand\descr[1]{{\boldmath\bfseries\uline{#1}}\hphantom{.}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{subproof}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[subproof]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}
\section{Title 1}
\section{Title 2}

\begin{subproof}
    \item \label{ITEMone}
    \descr{\( A\) is open} Let \( \epsilon>0\). Then \dots
    \item 
    \descr{\( A\) is bounded} Using subproof \ref{ITEMone}, we \dots
\end{subproof}
\end{document}
```