# Enumerated description with bold and underlined labels

Tags: numbering, enumerate, description

I want a kind of description environment but with numbered items.

I need an environment `MagicEnv` to be used like this:

```
We define and study a function `f`.
\begin{MagicEnv}
     \item[Definition of $f$] The function $f$ is defined as 
        \begin{equation}
               f(x)=x^2
        \end{equation}
   \item[$f(x)>0$]  Some proof and discussions.
  \item[$f$ is a bijection ] We prove that $f$ is a bijection
    \begin{MagicEnv}
       \item[$f$ is injective]   \label{my_label}
               Long proof here.
       \item[$f$ is surjective] 
            Proof here
    \end{MagicEnv}
\end{MagicEnv}
```

- The texts in `[...]` must be bold and underline in the same time.
- The numbering of the nested environment must recall the outside number. In this case we have the following numbers :

```
1 Definition of f
2 f>0
3 $f$ is a bijection
   3.1 injective
   3.2 surjective
```

- I want to be able to make references. Here `\ref{my_label}` should print "3.1". (work with hyperef if possible)

Related : [refstepcounter inside description item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640370/refstepcounter-inside-description-item)
The difference here is that I want to

- more than two level nesting
- the sub-sub items must be numbered with, e.g. 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, etc.

EDIT: make clear in the question that `MagicEnv` is the environment I am searching to produce. Also change the name "magic_env" -> "MagicEnv".

Comment: Please provide a fully compilable Minimal Working Example. Otherwise its hard to guess how to help. In general, `enumitem` should help. But e.g. `magic_env` seems defined by yourself and we don't know the definition. Plus, underscores in macro names are not the best idea.

Comment: @lukeflo Question edited.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really do what @lukeflo asked: don't post code fragments, but instead put the fragment into a compilable document that shows exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Also related: [Enumerated description list](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/30029)

Comment: I am not doing anything. My question is : I have not a clue how to do what I want. I am not in a situation like "I try to do X, I have <this code> and it produces <that error>".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in @lukeflo comment,you can do it with `enumitem` without to define any new environment, with nested `enumerate` and modified `\item`, named here `\litem` as in the manual §12.1

MWE :

```
\documentclass
[a5paper] %<!--for demo
{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,verbose=false]{geometry} %<!--for demo
\usepackage{enumitem}                            %<!-- neded 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic{enumi}}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic{enumi}.\arabic*}
\NewDocumentCommand{\litem}{o}{\item {\bfseries\boldmath #1\enspace}}

\begin{document}

We define and study a function $f$.
\begin{enumerate}
\litem[Definition of $f$] The function $f$ is defined as 
        \begin{equation}
               f(x)=x^2
        \end{equation}
   \litem[$f(x)>0$] Some proof and discussions.
   \litem[$f$ is a bijection] We prove that $f$ is a bijection
    \begin{enumerate}
       \litem[$f$ is injective]   \label{my_label}
               Long proof here.
       \litem[$f$ is surjective]
            Proof here
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Here is a reference to the first subitem of third item : \ref{my_label}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: updated code and picture to remove spurious coma.

EDIT 2:
I deliberately didn't underlined the bold labels because IMO (and most peopke here) it's a faulty typographic habit. If you really want it, load `ulem` or `soul` package and edit `\litem` definitiom accordingly.

EDIT 3: If you really want to nest more than 2 levels, add e.g.

```
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.\alph{*}}
```

Comment: That seems to be the solution ;)

Comment: It is possible also to underline each item this way:

' \litem[\underline{Definition of $f$}]'

Comment: @Raffaele I'm afraid it's a bad suggestion, as in addition to the ugly result stated in an edit, the standard `\underline` does not work very well and could lead to oddities if the involved math have a large depth. And moreover, one should, as far as possible, separate formating from content, and add, if any, formation commands in `\litem` *definition* and not its *use*.